# Selinux "Add context Rule to Semanage"

Tags: centos, redhat, fedora, selinux

As you add or change a new rule to fcontext semanage to any directory and apply, egg:

```
# How to add this rule for apply changes whit restoreconf -Rv
/var/www/html(/.*)?/media(/.*)?   system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0
# Here found all files have .bin and conf 
/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files
```

The result on whether you want to apply is to use the average httpd folder to write and read without problems with SELinux.

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/var/www/html/domain.com/media
#restorecon -Rv not apply changes
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? `chcon -u system_u -r object_r -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t filename`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your questions seems a little bit incomplete, but from what I gather you want to apply the `httpd_sys_rw_content_t` context on all `media` subfolders of your vhosts/domains and everything within it. These commands should do that for you:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/var/www/html/(.*)/media(/.*)?"
restorecon -Rv /var/www/html
```

This should apply the context type on all media subfolders in your domain folders.